# Microsoft Outlook Conditional Formatting Issues

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, mailchimp

I have coded my own email within Mailchimp and realised & forgot the problems with Microsoft Outlook when testing. I know that Microsoft is notoriously difficult and does not render HTML & CSS emails the same way as other platforms.

The main problem I have is my images exploding. I have looked at this article: (https://medium.com/@jasemiller/a-fix-for-outlook-image-issues-in-html-email-campaigns-b8dd1c8f7d16)
to find out the solution to this problem... to use conditional formatting for Microsoft Outlook.

Now I have a header which is two columns and has a logo in 1 column and a couple of Headers (h2,h3) in the other. I have messed around with this quite a bit but I feel I am nearly there. The problem is that Microsoft Outlook does not seem to render the code (div style="display:none") and continues to display code that it should ignore meaning the header is repeated.

```
    #templateHeader{
  /*@editable*/background-color:#001f5e;
}
.HeaderContainer{
 width:300px !important;
 max-width:300px !important;
}
#logo{
 max-width:100% !important;
 width:100% !important;
}
.LogoContainer img{
 max-width:100% !important;
 width:100% !important;
 float:left;
}       
           <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
           <tr>
             <td valign="top" id="templateHeader">
               <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                 <tr>
                    <td valign="top">

                  <!-- USE THIS CODE ONLY WHEN IN MICROSOFT / OUTLOOK & HIDE OTHER TABLES OUTSIDE OF THIS CONDITION STATEMENT NOT TO SHOW  -->
                  <!--[if mso]>
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <div class="LogoContainer">
                                    <table align="left" width="300">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img width="300" style="width=100px;" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d1231a3a58e3e61da03645dc0/images/a172f779-bbba-4902-a73a-551194e5274e.png" alt="Bold Consultancy Logo">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden; display:none; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">
                  <![endif]-->

                  <!-- USE THIS CODE ONLY WHEN NOT IN MICROSOFT / OUTLOOK -->
                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="HeaderContainer">
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top">
                        <div class="LogoContainer">     
                          <img id="logo" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/d1231a3a58e3e61da03645dc0/images/a172f779-bbba-4902-a73a-551194e5274e.png" alt="" mc:edit="preheader_leftcol">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <!-- END THE CONDITION STATEMENT -->
                  <!--[if mso]>
                    </div>
                  <![endif]-->

                  <!-- USE THIS CODE ONLY WHEN IN MICROSOFT / OUTLOOK & HIDE OTHER TABLES OUTSIDE OF THIS CONDITION STATEMENT NOT TO SHOW   -->
                  <!--[if mso]>
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <div class="HeaderTitles" mc:edit="preheader_rightcol">
                                    <h2>Email Title</h2>
                                    <h4>March 2019</h4>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden; display:none; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">
                  <![endif]-->

                  <!-- USE THIS CODE ONLY WHEN NOT IN MICROSOFT / OUTLOOK -->
                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="HeaderContainer">
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top">
                        <div class="HeaderTitles" mc:edit="preheader_rightcol">
                          <h2>Email Title</h2>
                          <h4>March 2019</h4>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <!-- END THE CONDITION STATEMENT -->
                  <!--[if mso]>
                    </div>
                  <![endif]-->


                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- // END MODULE: HEADER -->
```

The aim is to display a header with 2 columns one with a logo on the left and the right column with titles/headers in. So Microsoft Outlook should only render the code to display the columns in the conditional statement and should NOT repeat and show both sets of code. Anything outside of the condional statement should be hidden thanks to the DIV which states display:none. Currently it is not hiding the code outside of the statement and repeating and showing the header twice.

This problem is only for outlook as the email shows perfectly in other platforms.

Comment: have you tried `mso-hide:all;` in the CSS?

Comment: Yes, that is stated in each DIV within each conditional statement.

Comment: There is two parts to your code. Anything between `<!--[if mso]>` and `<![endif]-->` will be read by Outlooks only. And since you don't have code to say `not outlook`, everything else is being read as well. Made sense?

Answer (score 0):

You have `mso-hide: all;` in the wrong place.

Every section you have commented with

> USE THIS CODE ONLY WHEN NOT IN MICROSOFT / OUTLOOK

Is where it should be. Put it in the wrapping table elements. I just did a quick test in Litmus builder and it's not duplicating.

Comment: Actually there is a duplicate of Email title and March 2019 in all Outlooks if i use the exact code. Did you use OP's code with a doctype for litmus builder?

Comment: Alan, Syfer thanks very much for the tips and guidance. 

Alan, I went and inserted "style="mso-hide: all;" into the container tables in the sections that you suggested which are commented with:

USE THIS CODE ONLY WHEN NOT IN MICROSOFT / OUTLOOK

So what i have found is that it has removed the duplicate logo but it has unfortunately not removed the duplicate table that contains the title and date. 

Are there any thoughts as to why this would hide the table for the logo but not the table for the title and date?

Many thanks for the support

Comment: @JamieClague Use the CSS on the element you want to hide